# Burning to 100 GB BD-RE

Tags: burning, blu-ray

I have a Liteon iHBS312 Blu-ray burner and I am using Cyberlink Power2Go version 6.1.0.4715 as the burning software.

I recently purchased a Sony 100 GB BD-RE disc (for a data backup), but when I load it in the drive, the software says it is only 25 GB.

When I insert a dual-layer 50 GB disc, the size is correctly detected.

Is this a problem with the software? I realize v 6 is very old now, but it is the software that I got with the drive and it has always served me well, hence why I have never needed to upgrade (I only use it about once every two years when I do a full back-up of my NAS).

Or is it the Liteon burner itself?

Just looking for advice before I either purchase a new copy of the software or a new disc burner. Thank you.

Comment: Be wary of backing up to optical media... especially re-writable.

Comment: Are you sure the device supports the disk format your trying to use?

Comment: [The device only supports double layer BD-RE](http://www.liteonodd.com/en/bd-internal/item/bdinternal/ihbs312) you bought disks that your device doesn’t even support

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I wasn't sure, whether it was the device or the software

Comment: Thanks @Attie, it's just the last-ditch fail-safe. I use the NAS itself as the back-up, and every couple of years I dump it to disc

Comment: Ok, just bear in mind that optical media may not survive the "_couple of years_" period... :-)

Comment: btw, any recommendations for a burner that supports BDXL?

Comment: @danwellman - Questions seeking hardware recommendations are absolutely not within scope here at Superuser. Go to your favorite source for computer electronics, find a couple of options, then read user reviews.  [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=node%3D668573011&field-keywords=triple+layer+Blu-ray+burner&rh=n%3A668573011%2Ck%3Atriple+layer+Blu-ray+burner) and [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=Blu-ray+triple+layer+burner&N=-1&isNodeId=1) have several.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Blu-ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray) (pre-BD-XL) discs capacities are:

- 25 GB - single layer
- 50 GB - dual layer

[Blu-ray XL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray#BDXL) disc capacities are:

- 100 GB - tripple layer
- 128 GB - quadruple layer

---

The [Liteon iHBS312](http://www.liteonodd.com/en/bd-internal/item/bdinternal/ihbs312) does not list BD-XL as supported medium... in fact the [datasheet](http://www.liteonodd.com/datasheet/iHBS312_datasheet.pdf) states:

> The iHBS312 lets you record a maximum of 50 GB of data on a double layer disc.